# how to display data from list to single row in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem when displaying data from a table with 3 rows of data into a single row data.sample: row 1 = admin, 2 = superadmin , row 3 = guest. from the third row, I want to  results: admin; superadmin; guest

and this my code :

```
 listPosition = positionFacade.GetFullJabatan(userLogin);
 var listData = listPosition[0].NamaPosition.ToString();
 string convToSingleData = listData;
```

Answer (score 3):

.Net 3.5 and before

```
string convToSingleData = String.Join("; ", listPosition.Select(x => x.NamaPosition.ToString()).ToArray());
```

.Net 4 and after

```
string convToSingleData = String.Join("; ", listPosition.Select(x => x.NamaPosition.ToString()));
```

Comment: no result from your code sir... :(

Comment: What comes in `convToSingleData`?

Comment: from your code not result sir, from my code result : "admin"

Comment: string data = String.Join(",", listPosition.Select(x => x.NamaPosition));  it work... hehehe...

Comment: You wanted result as `admin; superadmin; guest`. Also what was wrong before?